# SQL statement with multiple keywords in string in LIKE statement

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rdbms, rodbc

I am trying to pull data based on multiple keywords from the same column.

Currently I have a SQL statement that works like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'
   OR CustomerName LIKE '_r%'
   OR CustomerName LIKE 'si%';
```

That works fine. What I am trying to achieve is to pass the keywords `c("a", "_r", "si")` as a vector. Like this:

```
keywords <- c("a", "_r", "si")

SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%' + keywords + '%';
```

That did not work. How do I submit a variable with a bunch of keywords into the like statement?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: `_` has special significance in the `LIKE` syntax and needs to be escaped if you wanted to match literal underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` and `paste/collapse=` . Within a sprintf format %s is replaced with the next argument and %% means %.

```
keywords <- c("a", "_r", "si")

sql <- keywords |>
  sprintf(fmt = "CustomerName LIKE '%%%s%%'") |>
  paste(collapse = " OR \n") |>
  sprintf(fmt = "SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE %s")

cat(sql, "\n")
```

giving:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a%' OR 
CustomerName LIKE '%_r%' OR 
CustomerName LIKE '%si%'
```

Comment: @g-grothendieck, is there way to not hardcode the three ` %%%`  , because the keywords can be two or three or four, I dont want to change the ` %%%`  everytime the number of keywords change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using `string_split()` and a `JOIN`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Find VARCHAR(max) = ('a%,_r%,si%')

Select Distinct A.* 
 From Customers A
 Join string_split(@Find,',') B
   on CustomerName like B.value
```